# Invalid Firebase Database path: Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'. how to solve this?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to download the audio URL of my mp3 audios stored in Firebase Storage and to save their URL and name in firebase database storage. but while uploading the data to firebase storage I am getting this error.

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/alarm-sachinbudak.appspot.com/o/Ringtone%2FPANI%20DI%20GAL.mp3?alt=media&token=fd442df3-c2b9-4ce3-b113-eb19957c4ee7. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

```
StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("Ringtone");
        reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
            Log.d("Tag","reference listed");
            for(StorageReference item:listResult.getItems()){

                Task<Uri> downloadUrlTask = item.getDownloadUrl();
                Task<StorageMetadata> downloadNameTask = item.getMetadata();

                Tasks.whenAll(downloadNameTask,downloadUrlTask).addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {

                    Methods methods = new Methods();
                    methods.firebse_ring_upload(downloadNameTask.getResult().getName(),downloadUrlTask.getResult());/////i am getting invalid database path in this line of code
                });
            }
        });
```

> my Method class

```
package com.example.alarm.Methods;

import android.net.Uri;

import com.example.alarm.Models.RingtoneModel;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Methods {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    public void firebse_ring_upload(String songName, Uri uri){
        RingtoneModel ringtoneModel = new RingtoneModel(songName,uri);

        try {
            database.getReference().child("Ringtones_Room").child(uri.toString().replace("[\\W+]","")).setValue(ringtoneModel);   /////i am getting invalid database path in this line of code
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

I tried placing the removeAll()Method but the problem remains.

> Note: my firebase database mode is not in the test mode
> Note: I also tried updating firebase security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

[image: firebase Storage Image]

please don't devote my question. I really tried many things.

Comment: make sure the file name / the value you upload does not contain any of these characters.

Comment: Can you log `uri.toString().replace("[\\W+]","")` and share the output ?